# How to add search bar in tabbar controller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, tabbarcontroller

I am working on a project in which i have to use search bar on tab bar controller on the top. i tried so many codes but not working i am sharing my code. please help me to overcome this problem.

```
UISearchBar *search = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    search.frame = CGRectMake(5 ,5, 300,45);
    search.delegate = self;
    search.showsBookmarkButton = NO;
    search.placeholder = @"Search/Select a Creative Service";
    search.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: What do you mean "no working"? Is it an interaction problem, a visual aspect problem (don't forget to add your search bar in your view: `[self.view addSubview:search];`)?

Comment: I already add this but still not showing the search bar on the tabbar controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your search bar as the title view:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one baseviewcontroller and add your UISearchBar in it. After that you can inherit your each tab's ViewController from that baseviewcontroller. So, in each tab of your UITabBarController you will get that UISearchBar.

The code you have written to create a `UISearchBar` is correct. Just add it to the view of the baseviewcontroller. Also, please ensure that frame is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with that too until I tried something and it turned out it's very simple !

All you need to do is to add UISearchBar and a Container View in one UIViewController and then from that Container View set the segue to your UITabBarController and here you go ! One search bar across all the tabs and the solution will also help in separating the logic of the search functionality from the tabs functionality as you will not be forced to implement a search view across all your tabs.

[image]

Here I created a view controller with 1 UIView containing a search bar and an account icon and also containing a Container View (The blue part) which will hold out TabBarController